# How could this corrupt list of folders and files have been generated from an xml file? (long shot)

Tags: c#

Hi this ones a head scratcher so any ideas would be appreciated. We're on final stages of testing our product, our field testers are noticing after our results are exported to USB, on a very rare occasion a list of empty corrupted folders and files are being generated from what seems to be the xml we generate and export (see screenshot).  These cannot be removed from the USB.  For various reason we have insufficient info and logging to determine what is going wrong.  Any ideas how this is possible?

For info here are the sequence of events after a user clicks 'export report':

1. .xml is serialized to the destination file path (USB) using NetDataContractSerializer and in the format:

```html
cartridge = arrayService.RetrieveCartridgeData(cartridge, includeAllAssociatedCartridges);
var fileName = "Cartridge" + ' ' + cartridge.CartridgeID + ' ' + DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss");
var xmlFilePath = filePath + @"\" + fileName + ".xml";

Cartridge deserializedCartridge = DetachFromContext(cartridge);

var ser = new NetDataContractSerializer();

using (var stream = File.OpenWrite(xmlFilePath))
{
        ser.Serialize(stream, deserializedCartridge);
}
```

[Screenshot of corrupt list of folders and files generated from an xml file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBR21.png)

2. After this we copy the xml into a staging area on the local PC with other files.
3. Staging area is zipped up and extracted back to USB.
4. xml file is deleted.

Comment: Always use *Path.Combine* to combine file paths. If you observe the names of the files/folders, they are *xml data* itself

Comment: It's not my code but I agree about Path.Combine.

Comment: You should log all the names of the *directories* and *files* into which you are writing then you might get a clue. It mostly looks like the xml content is being passed to the part of the code which handles the scenarios where the *Directory* / *File* does not exists and needs to be created .. Can you show us that part of the code?

Comment: Also, can you show us the parent folder's name?

Comment: The parent directory name is whatever the testers called it, in this case its in "7 Apr 16".  Where the directory file does not exist there is a catch all exception and this causes a error dialog to popup with the exception message. A fail usually occurs at the serialize.  Unfortunately we can't update the code as it's production testing.  Fixes will have to go in the next release.